# Переставить все нулевые элементы массива в конец. С

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка

С. Нужно переставить все нулевые элементы массива в конец. Код не обрабатывает 3 и больше нулей подряд, только два сортируются, остальные нули остаются на первоначальных местах. Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int N = 0;
float A[100];
do{  printf("Введите количество элементов\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
}while(N<1 || N>100);
           
printf("Введите элементы массива:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("A[%i]=", i);
        scanf("%f", &A[i]); }
    

  int i=0; int p=0;
  for (i=0,p=0; i<N; i++){
        while (A[i]==0 && i<N){
            p=i;
            for(p=i;p<N-1;p++) {
                A[p]=A[p+1];
            }
            A[N-1]=0;
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf(" A[%i] = %3.2f \n", i, A[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исправлять ваш ответ трудно, камня на камне не останется. Правильнее будет выучить идиоматическое решение. У вас есть два индекса в массиве: `i` пробегает все позиции, `j` - пробегает только не нулевые.

Цикл на псевдокоде:

```
i = 0
j = 0
while i < n:
    a[j] = a[i] # копируем всегда, так проще понять
    if a[i] != 0:
        j = j + 1 # продвигаем только если это был не ноль
    i = i + 1 # продвигаем всегда
```

Этот цикл делает некоторые вещи лишние, например копирует нули. Зато его проще понять. Пока мы не встретили первый ноль, все копирования бесполезны, так `i == j` и мы копируем элемент сам в себя. Но как только встречен первый ноль, `j` отстанет от `i` и элементы начнут перемещаться влево. Сперва на одну позицию, затем на большее расстояние, зависит от числа встреченных нулей.

Когда копирование завершено, в конце массива остался мусор. `j` как раз указывает на место где этот мусор начинается. Его надо убрать:

```
while j < n:
    a[j] = 0
    j = j + 1
```

Ниже код на C, который это делает. Он отличается, но использует те же идеи:

```
// gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 move_zeros.c

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// печатает массив
void print(int n, float a[/* n */]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%f", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// переносит нули в конец массива
void move_zeros(int n, float a[/* n */]) {
    int j = 0;

    // копируем ненулевые элементы в начало массива
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != 0) {
            assert(j <= i);
            // a[j++] - идиома С: записать значение и затем передвинуть индекс
            a[j++] = a[i];
        }
    }

    // заполняем нулями конец массива
    for (; j < n; ++j) {
        a[j] = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    float a[] = {0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6};
    int n = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

    print(n, a);
    move_zeros(n, a);
    print(n, a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int p=0;
for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    if (A[i]==0)
        p++;
    else    
       A[i-p] = A[i];
    }
```

и заполнить p нулями конец